# Проблема с зависимостями Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

Есть класс Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Type.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type")
    private Set<Type> type = new HashSet<Type>();
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Brand.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand")
    private Set<Brand> brand = new HashSet<Brand>();

    private String title;
    private long count;
    private long price;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Type> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Set<Type> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Set<Brand> getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(Set<Brand> brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

И класс Brand:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Brands")
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String brand;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Brands")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setTitle(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brand {" + "id=" + id + ", brand=" + brand + '}';
    }
}
```

Запускается нормально, но вылетает ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field com.alpha.bean.Product.brand to com.alpha.bean.Brand
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема

Comment: вы про какие зависимости спрашиваете? в каком месте возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как использовать JPA ознокомтесь с документацией

**ManyToOne** Определяет однозначную связь с другим классом, который имеет множественную множественность. Обычно нет необходимости указывать целевой объект *(targetEntity)*, поскольку он обычно может быть выведен из типа объекта, на который делается ссылка

**Пример**

```
 @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
 @JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
 public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

**OneToMany** Определяет многозначную связь с множественностью «один ко многим».

**Пример**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
public Set<Order> getOrders() { return orders; }
```

*getters/setters* должны соответствовать имени поля, у вас же это не соответвует в классе *Brand*

Пересоздай гетеры\сетеры в классе *Brand*. Поменяй антоации в классах. В классе *Brand* анотируй поле `private String brand;` и не как не `getId();`