# Не заполняются поля таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

Есть класс Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Type.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type")
    private Set<Type> type = new HashSet<Type>();
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Brand.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand")
    private Set<Brand> brand = new HashSet<Brand>();

    private String title;
    private long count;
    private long price;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Type> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Set<Type> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Set<Brand> getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(Set<Brand> brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Класс Brand:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Brands")
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String brand;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setTitle(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brand {" + "id=" + id + ", brand=" + brand + '}';
    }
}
```

И класс Type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Types")
public class Type {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type {" + "id=" + id + ", type=" + type + '}';
    }
}
```

Схема БД:

```
CREATE TABLE Brands
(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
BRAND VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Types
(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
TYPE VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Products
(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
TYPE_ID BIGINT REFERENCES Types(ID),
BRAND_ID BIGINT REFERENCES Brands(ID),
TITLE VARCHAR(100),
COUNT BIGINT,
PRICE BIGINT);
```

Все запускается и работает, но в браузере при выводе данных из таблицы Products именно поля brand и type почему-то null. Второй день маюсь, не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вожможно дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687059/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-spring-boot

Comment: GVArt, там проблема в другом была

Answer (score 0):

Сделай дебаг и посмотри значения этих полей в самом java коде. 
Если они null то скорее всего проблема в БД. Если все ОК, то что-то не правильно на стороне клиента. 
Как вариант у тебя может быть Lazy initialization. Тогда данные с таблиц Brand i Type будут подтягиваться только после product.getBrends(), product.getType()
Но скорее всего, если бы это было то у тебя был бы exception.